# How bad is it to add other attribute to an element or what other options are there?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element where I'm already using the `rel` attribute, but I would also like to add another attribute that I'll be using in JavaScript.

```
<a href="/" rel="blah" foo="bar">Link</a>
```

Is it alright to add other attributes? Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [html5 data-](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes. Even if you are not using html 5 you can be sure your work will still work and is futureproof.

e.g

```
<li class="user" data-city="Boston" data-food="Bacon">
```

Comment: Thxs, exactly what I needed. I should be building HTML5 websites anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to add new attributes through JavaScript, but if you add them directly in the source, your markup won't validate. If it's just one more attribute you need, there's a [`rev` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3.1) just like `rel`.

Comment: Adding arbitrary attributes could lead to issues if the users browser uses that attribute for some bit of logic or ui. You would need to make sure the attribute was unique. HTML5 provides the data- prefix which solves this issue.